# Determining season

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm making a script that determines the season based on the date. Here's what I have so far:

```
#$currentDate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd"
$currentDate = Get-Date 02-22

# Determining season
if ($currentDate -ge (get-date 03-01) -and $currentDate -le (get-date 05-31)) {
    $season = "Spring"
} elseif ($currentDate -ge (get-date 06-01) -and $currentDate -le (get-date 08-31)) {
    $season = "Summer"
} elseif ($currentDate -ge (get-date 09-01) -and $currentDate -le (get-date 11-30)) {
    $season = "Fall"
} elseif ($currentDate -ge (get-date 12-01) -and $currentDate -le (get-date 02-29)) {
    $season = "Winter"
} else {
    "Ryan Messed up"
    $season = "ERROR"
}

$season
```

It appears that dates in spring, summer and fall work as intended but winter doesn't. I suspect it is because PowerShell doesn't understand how a date (such as 02-22) can be greater than the 12th month AND less than the 2nd month at the same time.

I think I could fix this with a lengthy and ugly statement (like shoving a few more `-and` operators and parentheses in there, or use the `-or` operator but I'm more interested in knowing the best practice/most efficient way to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alreadxy mentioned [function Get-Season](https://www.lewisroberts.com/2016/09/21/powershell-for-seasons/)
A bit simplified and made a bit more locale independent:

```
Function Get-Season([datetime]$Date){
    If (!$Date) {$Date = Get-Date} #If date was not provided, assume today.
    # The dates are obviously not exactly accurate and are best guesses
    $Spring = Get-Date -Day 20 -Month 03 -Year $Date.Year
    $Summer = Get-Date -Day 21 -Month 06 -Year $Date.Year
    $Autumn = Get-Date -Day 22 -Month 09 -Year $Date.Year
    $Winter = Get-Date -Day 21 -Month 12 -Year $Date.Year
    $Season = switch($Date) {
        {($_ -lt $Spring)}  {"Winter";Break}
        {($_ -lt $Summer)}  {"Spring";Break}
        {($_ -lt $Autumn)}  {"Summer";Break}
        {($_ -lt $Winter)}  {"Autumn";Break}
        {($_ -ge $Winter)}  {"Winter"}
    }
    "{0:d} is in season {1}" -f $Date,$Season
}
```

Sample output (my locale short date format is yyyy-MM-dd)

```
> Get-Season
2018-06-21 is in season Summer

> Get-Season (Get-Date).adddays(-1)
2018-06-20 is in season Spring
```

Comment: Didn't summer begin today?

Comment: You are right, just discovered that myself and that the code I took over was partly wrong - changed above.

Comment: It was intentional. I went by northern meteorological season dates rather than astronomical season dates to make it easier on my eyes and more user friendly for the eventual purpose (Spring in June would seem weird). But yes it dawned on me that this would be the perfect day to test if my script works lol.

Regardless, that's a really interesting way of doing it and your code taught me a thing or two. I do have another question open that I actually am stuck on though if you get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan I did refer to the original code which sets the dates and then incorrectly compares `-le` insted of `-lt`

Comment: @lotPings Oops! Good catch! I may end up using this instead of what I ended up doing since it looks so nice. I do have another question open regarding this that you may be able to answer if you have the time. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Handles leap years where February ends on the 29th. While this isn't the typical definition of when winter ends, a "season" could be related to business or sports where ending on the last of the month makes more sense.

```powershell
param (
    [DateTime] $Date = (Get-Date -Format "MM-dd")
)

$endOfFebruary = "02-28"
try {
    $date = Get-Date 02-29
    if ($date -ne $null) { $endOfFebruary = $date.ToString("mm-dd") }
}
catch {
}

$seasons = @{
    Spring = @{ Start = "03-01"; End = "05-31" };
    Summer = @{ Start = "06-01"; End = "08-31" };
    Fall   = @{ Start = "09-01"; End = "11-30" };
    Winter = @{ Start = "12-01"; End = $endOfFebruary };
}

$currentSeason = $null

foreach ($season in $seasons.Keys)
{
    $start = Get-Date $seasons[$season].Start
    $end = Get-Date $seasons[$season].End
    if ($season -eq "Winter") {
        if ($Date -ge $start -or $Date -le $end) { $currentSeason = $season }
    } else {
        if ($Date -ge $start -and $Date -le $end) { $currentSeason = $season }
    }
}

Return $currentSeason
```

Output

```
PS C:\Code\PowerShell> .\Get-Season.ps1 -Date (Get-Date "04-15")
Spring
PS C:\Code\PowerShell> .\Get-Season.ps1 -Date (Get-Date "07-15")
Summer
PS C:\Code\PowerShell> .\Get-Season.ps1 -Date (Get-Date "12-14")
Winter
PS C:\Code\PowerShell> .\Get-Season.ps1 -Date (Get-Date "11-14")
Fall
```